# MDX for duration and time of day

Tags: mdx, data-warehouse

I am creating a data warehouse to store user session data. My current star schema looks like this:

**session_fact**

- session_id
- user_id
- session_duration
- date_id (ref date_dimension)
- time_if_day_id (ref time_of_day_dimension)

**date_dimension**

- date_id
- quarter
- month
- date_of_month

**time_of_day_dimension**

- time_of_day_id
- hour_of_day
- minute_of_hour

The session fact will link to the date and time of day dimensions using the *start time* of a session.

Problem:
I would like to create an MDX query that returns the 'active' sessions for each hour of a day.
E.g. for one day we may have these sessions:

```
session id |start time |duration
session 1  |10am       |1hr
session 2  |10am       |2hr
```

I would like to retrieve data in this form:

```
time of day |active session count
10am        |2
11am        |1
```

Any ideas? I'm very happy to restructure the schema following advice, I just don't know how I should do so.

Thanks for reading this.

Pat

Answer (score 0):

If you have the necessary hardware resources (disk space), the problem could be easily solved by creating a periodic snapshot fact table.  The grain would be hourly so you would have a record for each session that was active that hour.  This would GREATLY simplify the query to pull active sessions by hour...

```
SELECT
   [Measures].[Active Session Count] ON 0,
   (
      [Date].[Date].[Date].Members *
      [Time].[Hour].[Hour].Members 
   ) ON 1
FROM 
   [Cube]
```

Comment: Thanks iPolvo. That was the solution we have come up with so far, but we're dealing with 500 million records per year, and an average session duration of 4 hours. And disk space is limited at the moment - we're only new to dw and ew have to prove it before we jump fully in. we had considered having some sort of rollup process that gives us hour granularity for the past month only. Do you think that a complex MDX query is 'possible' for solving our problem?